# Unknown ARP Request

Tags: arp

I'm looking at the ARP packages in my network and have come over a request that I can't classify. Here is the content of Ethernet Header and ARP that I have problem with.

> ```
> Ethernet Header
>      |-Source Address      : b8:ae:ed:7f:9c:3b
>      |-Destination Address : f4:4d:30:6b:c7:e7
>      |-Protocol : 806
> Ether_ARP
> Sender:      192.168.1.37    b8:ae:ed:7f:9c:3b
> Target:      192.168.1.76    f4:4d:30:6b:c7:e7
> Format of hardware address.   = 0x0001
> Format of protocol address.   = 0x0800
> Length of hardware address.   = 0x06
> Length of protocol address.   = 0x04
> ARP opcode (command)          = 0x0001
> ```

With the opcode = 1 I only know of ARP Request, Probe and Announce and all of these use boadcast MAC address in the destination address.

Appreciate if someone can explain to me what I'm seeing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is in section 2.3.2.1 of RFC1122 which talks about refreshing the ARP cache for known hosts using a Unicast Poll. Pretty sure this is what you're seeing. ARP is normally 'taught' without mentioning unicast requests because the original intent for the protocol (RFC826) was as a mechanism for discovery using broadcast requests. These days the vast majority of ARP traffic on a network is RFC1122 style cache updates using unicast requests. Very confusing when you're expecting to only see broadcasts.